# What would be the range for the function $f(x)=\log_3(5+4x-x^2)$?

Tags: functions, inequality, logarithms, quadratics

I need to find the range of the function $$f(x)=\log_3(5+4x-x^2)$$

Here's what I tried to do:

First I found the domain, by setting, $$5+4x-x^2 > 0$$

$$\implies x^2-5-4x<0$$
$$\implies (x-5)(x+1)<0$$
So, from here, the domain is $x \in (-1,5)$

So here the domain is a finite open interval. Also, I know that, $\log_ak$, where $a>1$ is an increasing function. But I have no idea where to go from here. A detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just remember at elementary level logarithm is defined only for positive numbers, but actually it is defined for negative and complex numbers as well.

Comment: @Arjang I'm only talking about its validity on the reals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac d {dx} (5+4x-x^{2})=4-2x$. This is positive in $(-1,2)$ and negative in $(2,5)$. So the function $5+4x-x^{2}$ is increasing up to $x=2$ and then it is decreasing. Its maximum is $9$ and its infimum is $0$ (the limit of he function as $ x\to -1$ or $x \to 5$). Hence the maximum  value of $f$ is $\log_3 9=2$ and there is no minimum. [$\log_3 x \to -\infty$ as $x$ tends to $0$ through positive values].

Comment: My book states that the answer for the range is $(-\infty, 2]$, how did the minimum value of $-\infty$ come?

Comment: I think you are confused about the notation. The symbol you wrote here does not mean that the minimum is $-\infty.$

Comment: My answer matches the given answer. The minimum value is not attined anywhere in the domain and the limiting value at the end points are both $\log_3 0=-\infty$. So  the  range is $(-\infty, 2]$.. @Techie5879

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, I see that I was just being stupid now. Thanks

Comment: Good question.  I am editing my answer so that you have a detailed answer.

Comment: @James, no need, I did look at the graph and got my answer that the logarithm approaches negative infinity as x approaches 0

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you explain why the infimum is attained for when x approaches $-1$ or $5$?

Comment: @Techie5879 It is because the quadratic function is increasing in $(-1,2)$ and decreasing in $(2,5)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That is the quadratic's behaviour right? The quadratic is increasing and decreasing in those intervals

Comment: @Techie5879 Yes, I have corrected.the comment.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Got it. Cleared all doubts

Answer (score 3):

We have that $5+4x-x^2 = -(x-2)^2 +9.$ The range of this function is $(-\infty, 9],$ since logarithm is defined for positive numbers only, we consider the interval $(0, 9].$ Since logarithm is increasing and continuous function, the range of $f$ is $(-\infty, 2].$

Edit:

Again consider the graph of $g(x)= \log_3(x).$ Look at the graph carefully. Our function $g$ is NOT defined for negative numbers. Furthermore, if $x$ approaches to $0,$ then $\log_3(x)$ approaches to $-\infty.$ Does this help?

Comment: Why is the min value of the logarithm $-\infty$??

Comment: Look at the graph of the quadratic. It's a concave down parabola. Them minimum is NOT defined here. You could say the minimum approaches to $-\infty.$

Comment: Yes that was what I tried to mean but framed it very poorly unfortunately. I apologize

Comment: Yes I did look at the graph and its clear now. Thanks